# Python build error in centos 7.0

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, centos7

I want to install Python 3.4.3 in Centos 7.0.
I did the following:

wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.4.3/Python-3.4.3.tar.xz

tar xvfJ Python-3.4.3.tar.xz

cd Python-3.4.3

./configure --prefix=/ (As I want to install in root "/" directory and not /usr/local which is where it stored by default)

make

--> This is what I get after make command

Python build finished successfully!
The necessary bits to build these optional modules were not found:
_tkinter
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.

after this I want to run make test and make altinstall (I want two versions of Python )

Any help on How to install this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If, like me, you install your own python3 on CentOS (currently, I install 3.6.x), and you need tkinter functionality, this is what you need to do:

1. yum install tkinter tk-devel
2. wget, uncompress, ./configure, make, and make altinstall as normal.

In more detail, for those that would like to see it:

1. sudo su -
2. yum -y install tkinter tk-devel
3. wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.1/Python-3.6.1.tar.xz #or whichver version is newest
4. tar xf Python-3.?.?.tar.xz
5. cd Python-3.?.?
6. ./configure && make && make altinstall
7. python3.6 -c 'import tkinter; tkinter._test()'

Answer (score 1):

Python 3.4.3 is already available in [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL), but if you insist on building it from source then you will need to install, among other development packages, `tk-devel`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I downloaded EPEL (yum install epel-release) even did yum install tk-devel (no package found error) and latte did ./configure --prefix=/ and then did make and make test. Many errors came: ERROR: test_connect (test.test_ssl.NetworkedTests)

Comment: Once you've installed EPEL, you can install the `python34` package.