# How to fix "ssl module in Python is not available" in CentOs

Tags: python, centos

New Python 3.7.1 installation on GoDaddy VPS CentOs 7.
Attempt pip3 install virtualenv or python 3 -m pip install virtualenv and get:

pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.

openssl-devel installed and up to date

This question has been asked and answered many times, but the solutions I've found have not solved my problem.
Thank you all!

I tried the CentOs and Linux-based solutions in the following:

["SSL module in Python is not available" when installing package with pip3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41328451/ssl-module-in-python-is-not-available-when-installing-package-with-pip3)
      # To allow for building python ssl libs
      yum install openssl-devel
      # Download the source of *any* python version
      cd /usr/src
      wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.1/Python-3.7.1.tar.xz
      tar xf Python-3.7.1.tar.xz 
      cd Python-3.7.1

```
  # Configure the build w/ your installed libraries
  ./configure

  # Install into /usr/local/bin/python3.6, don't overwrite global python bin
  make altinstall
```

[Trying to install packages with Python 3.7.2 pip causes TSL/SSL errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54310843/trying-to-install-packages-with-python-3-7-2-pip-causes-tsl-ssl-errors)

["SSL module in Python is not available" when installing package with pip3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41328451/ssl-module-in-python-is-not-available-when-installing-package-with-pip3)

[pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45954528/pip-is-configured-with-locations-that-require-tls-ssl-however-the-ssl-module-in)

`yum install zlib-devel bzip2-devel openssl-devel ncurses-devel sqlite-devel readline-devel tk-devel gdbm-devel db4-devel libpcap-devel xz-devel`

[pip cannot confirm SSL certificate: SSL module is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44290926/pip-cannot-confirm-ssl-certificate-ssl-module-is-not-available)

["ssl module in Python is not available"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49094768/ssl-module-in-python-is-not-available)
    and
[pip cannot confirm SSL certificate: SSL module is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44290926/pip-cannot-confirm-ssl-certificate-ssl-module-is-not-available)

```
  `uncommented suggestions for CentOs
  make install failed:
    gcc -pthread -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall    -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration   -I. -I./Include     -DUSE_SSL -I/include -I/include/openssl -c ./Modules/_ssl.c -o Modules/_ssl.o
    ./Modules/_ssl.c:74:6: error: #error "libssl is too old and does not support X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set1_host()"
    ./Modules/_ssl.c: In function ‘_ssl_configure_hostname’:
    ./Modules/_ssl.c:861: error: implicit declaration of function ‘SSL_get0_param’
    ./Modules/_ssl.c:861: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
    ./Modules/_ssl.c:863: error: implicit declaration of function ‘X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set1_host’
    ./Modules/_ssl.c:869: error: implicit declaration of function ‘X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set1_ip’
    ./Modules/_ssl.c: In function ‘_ssl__SSLContext_impl’:
    ./Modules/_ssl.c:2988: error: ‘X509_CHECK_FLAG_NO_PARTIAL_WILDCARDS’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    ./Modules/_ssl.c:2988: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
    ./Modules/_ssl.c:2988: error: for each function it appears in.)
    ./Modules/_ssl.c:3093: error: implicit declaration of function ‘SSL_CTX_get0_param’
    ./Modules/_ssl.c:3093: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
    ./Modules/_ssl.c:3099: error: implicit declaration of function ‘X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set_hostflags’
    ./Modules/_ssl.c: In function ‘get_verify_flags’:
    ./Modules/_ssl.c:3397: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
    ./Modules/_ssl.c: In function ‘set_verify_flags’:
    ./Modules/_ssl.c:3410: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
    ./Modules/_ssl.c: In function ‘set_host_flags’:
    ./Modules/_ssl.c:3573: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
    make: *** [Modules/_ssl.o] Error 1`
```

https://www.tomordonez.com/pip-install-ssl-module-python-is-not-available.html

Answer (score 45):

This works for me on CentOS 7.9 with Python 3.10.9 based on https://bugs.python.org/issue47201

This edits `configure` instead of `Modules/Setup`:

```
sudo yum install -y epel
sudo yum install -y openssl11-devel
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.9/Python-3.10.9.tgz
tar zxvf Python-3.10.9.tgz
cd Python-3.10.9
sed -i 's/PKG_CONFIG openssl /PKG_CONFIG openssl11 /g' configure
./configure --enable-optimizations
sudo make altinstall
# The following should run without errors if SSL was properly compiled
python3.10 -m ssl
```

If a more recent version of Python works for you, then perhaps it may be useful to others to leave a comment about it.

Comment: This worked well on Centos7

Comment: Worked for me only after using `epel-release.noarch` rather than `epel`

Comment: I got  No module named '_ssl' when running the last line

Comment: This works on Amazon Linux 2, minus installing `epel`.

Comment: @Fadwa I was getting the same error but I wasn't running all of the lines, I skipped some because I thought I had already installed the packages. I redid all the lines and it worked. I'm using Amazon Linux 2

Comment: This works also on Centos 7.9 and Python3.12. Of cource you have to install openssl1.1.1 first https://gist.github.com/Bill-tran/5e2ab062a9028bf693c934146249e68c

Comment: For optimizations option `--enable-optimizations` in CentOS 7 see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70840635/9913319

Comment: I also had this error: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44268222/9913319 and other errors. Yo should install `yum install zlib-devel bzip2-devel openssl-devel ncurses-devel sqlite-devel readline-devel tkinter tk-devel gdbm-devel db4-devel libpcap-devel xz-devel libffi-devel`

Answer (score 17):

Here is a working solution for Python 3.7.9 and CentOS 7.8.2003:

```
su - root
yum install gcc openssl-devel bzip2-devel libffi-devel zlib-devel -y
cd /usr/src
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.9/Python-3.7.9.tgz
tar xzf Python-3.7.9.tgz
cd Python-3.7.9
```

In `/usr/src/Python-3.7.9/Modules/Setup.dist`, uncomment these 4 lines:

```
SSL=/usr/local/ssl
_ssl _ssl.c \
    -DUSE_SSL -I$(SSL)/include -I$(SSL)/include/openssl \
    -L$(SSL)/lib -lssl -lcrypto
```

And finally:

```
./configure --enable-optimizations
make altinstall
```

Comment: Thank You, Now I can use a on centos8 a most recent version of Python than the 3.6.8

Comment: I don't seem to find Setup.dist in python 3.10.5.. Do we have fix for it?

Comment: There is no `/usr/src/Python-3.7.9/Modules/Setup.dist` file.

Comment: Also, look in `/usr/src/Python-3.x.x/Modules/Setup` for other versions of Python

Answer (score 12):

I have seen this error when the version of openssl is incompatible. This is more likely when you're installing a newer Python (such as 3.7.2) on a not-as-recent version of the Linux system.

I would check to see what version of SSL libraries are expected with this version of Python and if necessary, install them locally.

This is a basic description of building the SSL libraries: [DreamHost instructions for Installing Local OpenSSL Version](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001435926-Installing-OpenSSL-locally-under-your-username)

You will want to build Python again with the following option added to your invocation of ./config:

```
--with-openssl=/path/to/your/local/install
```

Comment: This worked well on a Red Hat 8.4 with openssl 1.1.1k and python 3.7.11

Answer (score 4):

Minor correction to a prev answer by Kevin Lemaire

Here is a working solution for Python 3.7.9 and CentOS 7.8.2003:

```sh
su - root
yum install gcc openssl-devel bzip2-devel libffi-devel zlib-devel -y
cd /usr/src
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.9/Python-3.7.9.tgz
tar xzf Python-3.7.9.tgz
cd Python-3.7.9
```

In Modules/Setup, uncomment these 4 lines: <<< minor correction

```
SSL=/usr/local/ssl
_ssl _ssl.c \
    -DUSE_SSL -I$(SSL)/include -I$(SSL)/include/openssl \
    -L$(SSL)/lib -lssl -lcrypto
```

And finally:

```sh
./configure --enable-optimizations
make altinstall
```

Comment: This works for CENTOs 7 and Python 3.8.14, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Please read [this article](https://joshspicer.com/python37-ssl-issue)

Basically you need to install openssl first and uncomment ssl related lines in Modules/Setup file in python source code before to make install.
This worked to me on installing Python 3.8.

Answer (score 3):

I solve the problem by Matt's answer.

For those who can not find the package epel:

```
$ yum install -y epel
......
No package epel available.

$ yum search epel
......
================================ N/S matched: epel ================================
epel-release.noarch : Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux repository configuration

$ yum install epel-release.noarch
```

Answer (score 1):

For me what worked on CentOS 7.9 and using the following guide: https://bugs.python.org/issue47201

Essentially after downloading Python 3.11.3 and unpacking it, from its folder I ran:

```
sudo yum install -y epel
sudo yum install -y openssl11-devel
sed -i 's/PKG_CONFIG openssl /PKG_CONFIG openssl11 /g' configure
```

Then I ran:

```
./configure --enable-optimizations
make altinstall
```

This successfully installed python3.11 and pip3.11 with the ssl properly configured and the error was not shown anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't the answer for centOS, but for the other poor souls like me who couldn't find the answer elsewhere, the accepted answer works with the following modifications on an ubuntu install:

```
sudo apt install libssl-dev liblzo2-dev libpam0g-dev
sed -i 's/PKG_CONFIG openssl /PKG_CONFIG openssl11 /g' configure
./configure --enable-optimizations
sudo make altinstall
```

In my case, I'd altinstalled python3.7 and was hitting the same error as reported in this ticket.

Lastly wanted to add that, these steps will repair your existing (alt)install. You don't need to (nor should you, from what I've read) clean up a python install unless you really know what you're doing.

Cheers

Answer (score -1):

Taking inspiration from the two answers on this thread, downloading and extracting OpenSSL 1.1.1o and then running the following sequence of commands solved the problem for me.

```
su - root
yum install gcc openssl-devel bzip2-devel libffi-devel zlib-devel -y
cd /usr/src
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.9/Python-3.7.9.tgz
tar xzf Python-3.7.9.tgz
cd Python-3.7.9
./configure --enable-optimizations --with-openssl=/path/to/your/local/install
make install
```

Comment: What is `/path/to/your/local/install`? Path to OpenSSL sources? To OpenSSL binaries?

Answer (score -7):

Solution: Python 3.6.2 instead of 3.7.1

Comment: While this probably fixes the issue, I wouldn't call it a solution. There are features of 3.7 that aren't included in 3.6.