# CentOs7: ssl module in Python is not available

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl-certificate, centos7, python-ssl

I am on `CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)`, installed `python3.10.12` from source using the following script

```
sudo yum update

sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
sudo yum install zlib-devel bzip2-devel \
  openssl-devel ncurses-devel sqlite-devel \
  readline-devel tk-devel gdbm-devel \
  libffi-devel xz-devel


wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.12/Python-3.10.12.tgz


tar -xvf Python-3.10.12.tgz

./configure --enable-optimizations

make

sudo make altinstall


Python 3.10.12 (main, Jul  8 2023, 16:54:43) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information


sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3.10 /usr/local/bin/python3
```

But, when trying pip, I got this error

```
There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/tutor/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

Tried to list the ssl modules installed for python3, and got this
[image]

Also, when trying

```
python3.10 -m ssl
```

I got

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ssl'
```

I found some [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5128893/2224801) that suggests adding `--with-ssl` option while building, and another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75114549/2224801) that deosn't use this option at all. How can I solve this?

Comment: @larsks Thank you for your comment. 
I already installed it, you can find it in the third line of my installation script
`sudo yum install zlib-devel bzip2-devel openssl-devel ..`

Comment: I've edited your question to make this list of packages easier to read without scrolling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at your `./configure` output, you will see:

```
checking for --with-openssl-rpath...
checking whether OpenSSL provides required APIs... no
checking for --with-ssl-default-suites... python
```

So the `configure` script is failing to detect necessary support in OpenSSL. If we look at `config.log`, we find:

```
configure:17849: checking whether OpenSSL provides required APIs
configure:17895: gcc -pthread -o conftest  -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -fvisibility=hidden       conftest.c -lcrypt -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm -lssl -lcrypto   >&5
conftest.c:410:2: error: #error "OpenSSL >= 1.1.1 is required"
 #error "OpenSSL >= 1.1.1 is required"
```

And there's your problem; Python 3.10 requires OpenSSL version 1.1.1 or later, and CentOS 7 only provides 1.0.2.

If you want ssl support in your custom built Python, you'll need to first build a recent version of OpenSSL and install it somewhere on your system, and then provide `configure` with appropriate arguments to find it.

---

Alternately:

- If you need Python 3.10 on CentOS 7, consider running running it in a container.
- Consider installing a more recent operating system. CentOS 7 was originally released in **2014**. That's almost 10 years ago. While it receives security updates, it doesn't receive feature updates, so it's simply not going to have recent versions of software.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
How Can I get the output of `./configure` ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. When you run `./configure --enable-optimizations`, it produces lots of output. That's it. Look at it.

Comment: ah yes, will do.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer. Especially the final point regarding the age of CentOS 7. I used to be a Linux support engineer which mean supporting Suse SLES and Redhat RHEL (which is what CentOS is based on). They are very conservative distros that evolve slowly and are targeted at corporations which value stability. I'm always perplexed when I see someone being unhappy because installing the latest version of some app isn't as easy as it would be on any non-"enterprise" distro.