# Install Python in docker

Tags: python, docker

CentOS 7.5
My docker file is

```
FROM centos:7

WORKDIR /app
COPY openssl-1.1.1.tar.gz /app
RUN yum install -y gcc bzip2-devel libffi-devel zlib-devel wget
RUN yum -y groupinstall "Development Tools"
RUN tar xvzf openssl-1.1.1.tar.gz
RUN cd openssl-1.1.1 && ./config --prefix=/usr/local/openssl no-zlib && make && make install
RUN ln -s /usr/local/openssl/include/openssl /usr/include/openssl && \
    ln -s /usr/local/openssl/lib/libssl.so.1.1 /usr/local/lib64/libssl.so && \
    ln -s /usr/local/openssl/bin/openssl /usr/bin/openssl
RUN echo "/usr/local/openssl/lib">> /etc/ld.so.conf
RUN ldconfig -v
RUN openssl version
RUN rm -rf penssl-1.1.1
RUN rm penssl-1.1.1.tar.gz

COPY Python-3.10.4.tgz /app
RUN tar xvzf Python-3.10.4.tgz
RUN echo "export CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/openssl/include" >> ~/.bashrc
RUN echo "export LDFLAGS=\"-L/usr/local/openssl/lib -lssl -lcrypto\"" >> ~/.bashrc
RUN echo "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/openssl/lib" >> ~/.bashrc
RUN source ~/.bashrc
RUN cd Python-3.10.4 && ./configure --enable-optimization && make -j$(nproc) && make altinstall

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

But it seems in the Python installation part, "make altinstall" is not correctly executed.

When I run the docker container (docker run -it), then run python3 and try to import ssl, it prompts "_ssl module is not found"
But after I run "make altinstall" again from Python-3-10.4 folder manually, then ssl module is there.
Anyone has an idea what the issue is? Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Welcome! Does this answer helps: [CentOS 7.9 with Python 3.10.9 based on issue47201](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75114549/21350362)?

Comment: None of the lines that mention `.bashrc` have any effect; that file and other shell dotfiles aren't usually read in Docker.  Why not just install OpenSSL into `/usr/local/lib` (in the image filesystem) so you don't have to change paths?  Do you _need_ to install OpenSSL from source?  Or Python?  (Can you just use the prebuilt Docker Hub `python:3.10` image?)

Comment: @Dmitry. It works. Really appreciate!

Comment: @DavidMaze Thank you for the answer. I believe it will work. But as I tried with Dmitry's solution, and it works, will put your suggestion in my backlog and try it later :)